# Print list in specific format

Tags: r, list, for-loop, bounding-box

I have a list with 72 bounding boxes. This is the dput (just 5 of them).

```
list(`1` = c(V1 = 7.426758, V2 = 47.398349, V3 = 7.8508356, V4 = 47.686178
), `10` = c(V1 = 7.8508356, V2 = 47.686178, V3 = 8.2749132, V4 = 47.974007
), `11` = c(V1 = 8.2749132, V2 = 47.686178, V3 = 8.6989908, V4 = 47.974007
), `12` = c(V1 = 8.6989908, V2 = 47.686178, V3 = 9.1230684, V4 = 47.974007
), `13` = c(V1 = 9.1230684, V2 = 47.686178, V3 = 9.547146, V4 = 47.974007
))
```

and this is the desired output:

```
c(7.4267580,47.3983490,7.8508356,47.6861780)
```

How can I print each bounding box in the desired output using a for loop?

Comment: `dput(lapply(your_list, unname))` should do the trick, if I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get this output by running

```
dput(lapply(your_list, unname))
```

However, if you want to *save* the stringified vectors to a new vector, there’s a more direct way, via the `toString` function. first off, here’s what `toString` does to a vector:

```
toString(1 : 5)
# [1] "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

Great! That’s almost what we want; we just need to put it into `c(…)`:

```
paste0('c(', toString(1 : 5), ')')
# [1] "c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)"
```

And now we need to apply this operation to every element in the original list. [`vapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) does that:

```
result = vapply(your_list, \(x) paste0('c(', toString(x), ')'), character(1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will print each element of the list in the required format:

```
have <- list(`1` = c(V1 = 7.426758, V2 = 47.398349, V3 = 7.8508356, V4 = 47.686178
), `10` = c(V1 = 7.8508356, V2 = 47.686178, V3 = 8.2749132, V4 = 47.974007
), `11` = c(V1 = 8.2749132, V2 = 47.686178, V3 = 8.6989908, V4 = 47.974007
), `12` = c(V1 = 8.6989908, V2 = 47.686178, V3 = 9.1230684, V4 = 47.974007
), `13` = c(V1 = 9.1230684, V2 = 47.686178, V3 = 9.547146, V4 = 47.974007
))

for (item in have) {dput(unname(item))}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks good. How can I save each row (bbox) as a variable in the dput format?

Comment: @shaun_m Please, no. That's really not how you're supposed o use `assign`. Use regular assignment together with a vector.